# Possible with vue routes to have a unique id per route (suffix)

Tags: vue.js

Let's say I have a route /myroute

Is it possible to have some different suffix on the rote as well that maps to myroute

/myroute-ff89u91209091

For example with this above, is it possible that the tag will be unique but still requests map to my route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wildcard in your route definition to match the string:

```js
routes: [
    { path: '/myroute-*', component: MyRoute },
]
```

Route params and route queries might have also solved your requirements but this will work.